Geometrical construction giving the roots of a quadratic in Hardy's "A course of Pure Mathematics".

I am unable to understand what I must demonstrate to show that $QX$ and $QY$ are the geometric constructions corresponding to the roots of the standard quadratic equation, nor how to prove it. Help would be appreciated.
Edit: In the image, Hardy purports to have geometrically constructed the roots to the standard quadratic equation in the form $ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0$. He claims that the segments $QX$ and $QY$ respectively form the roots of the equation given the construction, a statement assumed without proof. I am looking for a synthetic proof to the same. My presumption is I have to use similarity of triangles.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The solution isn't given. Hardy has created a construction as described in the image and claims without proof that QX and QY correspond to the roots of the standard quadratic ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0. I'm looking for a proof of the same.

I have modified your title in order that it better "reflects" the content of your question.

MN may not be a diameter, if adjusted appropriately, it might just be a chord. However I can get the relationship of I assume triangles PQY and PQX are similar. How this ratio leads me to conclude QX or QY are roots is a mystery.

For $QX$ you must use similarity between $MPP'$ and $XMQ'$, as well as $XM\cdot XP=XQ^2$ (power of a point) and $XP^2-XQ^2=4$ (Pythagoras).

You might be interested by this and that.

See as well here.

@Inteligenti pauca,  your suggestion led me to some progress, but eventually I'm finding some of the equations redundant and am unable to solve it to get an explicit value for QX without reducing by to solving the quadratic equation.

From the similarity between $MPP'$ and $XMQ'$,
and remembering that $PP'=-2a/b$, $QQ'=c/(2b)$
(I'm assuming $a>0$, $b<0$, $c<0$, which is the case of the figure),
you get:
$$
XP=\left(1-{2a\over bXQ+c/2}\right)XM.
$$
Combining that with $XM\cdot XP=XQ^2$ we obtain:
$$
XP^2=\left(1-{2a\over bXQ+c/2}\right)XQ^2.
$$
Finally, inserting that into $XP^2−XQ^2=4$ one has:
$$
{4\over XQ^2}={XP^2\over XQ^2}-1=-{2a\over bXQ+c/2},
$$
that is:
$$
-4(bXQ+c/2)=2aXQ^2
$$
and $XQ$ thus satisfies the given equation: $aXQ^2+2b XQ+c=0$.
An analogous reasoning can be made for $YQ$. Of course, for a complete proof, one should also examine the case when $a$ and $c$ have the same sign, so that $P'$ and $Q'$ lie on the same side of $PQ$.
